# SUP 2.2 + Android throw exception at Application.getInstance().setApplicationContext(this);

Tags: android, eclipse, sybase, sup

I try to use Sybase Unwired Platform with generated code for Android.
I have exception in following code:

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);    

Application app = Application.getInstance();
        
String AppName = "timesheets";
        
if (app.getApplicationIdentifier() == null)
    app.setApplicationIdentifier(AppName);

if (app.getApplicationContext() == null)
    app.setApplicationContext(this); //Place where app crashes
```

Debug window look like this:

[image: debug window]

All crashes after beginning of execution of that line:

[image: crash message box]

Android version is 4.1.2 (API 16)

Why does it crash?

Answer (score 0):

I don't even know what Sybase is, but I don't believe setting application context to Activity is good idea. `this` refers to Activity, doesn't it?

Actually, I can't even find that method in Android API:

```
Application.setApplicationContext(this)
```

Looked here:
[Application](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html)
and
[ContextWrapper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContextWrapper.html)
and
[Context](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html)

What are you trying to archive by this line?

Comment: this object is Activity. I just use sybase unwired platform code sample as sample. sample code is         Application app = Application.getInstance();
        app.setApplicationIdentifier("SUP101");
        app.setApplicationContext(SUP101SampleActivity.this); 
Application is equal com.sybase.mobile.Application. SUP101SampleActivity extends Activity.

Answer (score 0):

I corrected source to more clear form:

```
com.sybase.mobile.Application app = com.sybase.mobile.Application.getInstance();

String AppName = "timesheets";

if (app.getApplicationIdentifier() == null)
   app.setApplicationIdentifier(AppName);

if (app.getApplicationContext() == null)
   app.setApplicationContext(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

What I used to do in Android & SUP 2.1 is Application.getInstance().setApplicationContext(getApplicationContext());

I see you are still passing the activity as context. Try to pass the application context like I wrote in my line above.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 app.setApplicationContext(getApplicationContext());
```

Comment: Considering op asked why it was crashing, I think a little explanation might be in order.